# "Find a Stack Exchange community" search box clipped in Firefox

Tags: bug, design, top-bar, firefox

On all sites (as far as I've tested), the search text in the site selection dropdown clips off the top and bottom:

[image]

Setup: FF 58.0.2, Windows 10. Doesn't occur in Edge, haven't tested in Chrome.

Comment: No repro in Chrome, Win10.

Comment: I do see it in FF 58.0.1 64 bit on Mac.